# How to create function to validate dropdownlist in the backend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a small form with the help of **C#** and **ASP.NET MVC** and within this form I have a `dropdownlist` which shows some enabled states this depends on the value that comes in the form that in this case would be *FINISHED*.

I would like to place some restriction from the back-end to avoid that if the users change the values ​​of `disabled` from the console of the navigator, it does not allow him to send them, what I really need is to validate in the controller that this data is not sent.

The following is the code `dropdownlist` with its different options

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select id="ticketStatusInput" name="status" class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select a option</option>
<option value="ABT" disabled="">OPEN</option>
<option value="ASG">ASSIGNED</option>
<option value="CDO" disabled="">CLOSED</option>
<option value="ESU" disabled="">WAITING FOR USER</option>
<option value="PRC">IN PROCESS</option>
<option value="TMN">FINISHED</option>
</select>
```

The IDs of the states are ABT corresponds to the **OPEN** state, ASG corresponds to the **ASSIGNED** state, CDO corresponds to the **CLOSED** state, ESU, corresponds to the **USER WAITING** state, PRC corresponds to the **IN PROCESS** state and finally TMN corresponds to the **FINISHED** state.

This is the Javascript function which loads the data and the realization of its respective validation, it is clear that **TMN** corresponds to the FINISHED state .

```
function loadTicketDetails() {
    $(".fixed-action-btn").floatingActionButton();
    $(".fixed-action-btn").show("slow");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    document.getElementById("modalAceptNew").style.display = "none";

    const url = document.getElementById("allTicketData").value;

    window.hasRun = true;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            $("#StatusDiv select").val(data.Status);

            //Validation when FINISHED can be assigned to ASSIGNED/IN PROCESS
            if (data.Status == 'TMN') {

                $("#StatusDiv select option[value*='ABT']").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#StatusDiv select option[value*='CDO']").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#StatusDiv select option[value*='ESU']").prop("disabled", true);
            } 

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("There was an error loading the data, please try again.");
        }
    });

}
```

And finally the controller which is where some validation should be done in the back

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateTicketFromDetails()
        {
            var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"];
        try
            {
                TicketRegisterResult result;               
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    // I create a new record variable with all fields
                    var record = new TK_DT_RECORDS
                    {
                        TK_CT_STATUS_ID = ticketStatusInput,
                    };
                    // We update the ticket data (this will always be done)
                    var model = new TicketRegisterModel();
                    // We create the new record in the record table and insert it
                    result = model.UpdateTicket;

                    //If the ticket was not saved, the transaction is finished and we return the error message
                    if (!result.Success)
                        return Json(new TicketResult
                        {
                            IsValid = false,
                            Error = "The changes could not be saved, please try again."
                        });
                    scope.Complete();
                }   
            }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            //Failed to try to register data in the database
            foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);

            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "There was an error creating the ticket, please try again."
            });
        }
            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = true
            });
            }
```

The data will always be sent, because I have no control over that. what I need is a function that allows to control if the data is valid.

I found an article that talks about controller side data validation but it is not very clear to me as soon as I start with **C#**

[Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-page-application-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/)

**Business rule**

I have a dropdownlist where the values ​​of **OPEN**, **ASSIGNED**, **CLOSED**, **IS WAITING FOR USER**, **IN PROCESS**, **FINISHED**.

When the **FINISHED** value arrives in the dropdownlist, it can only be assigned to **ASSIGNED** or **IN PROCESS** means that the others are disabled.

**UPDATE:**

I present a problem with asynchronous function `<InputStatus>`

[image]

Comment: Instead of enabling or disabling hardcoded options, I believe it would be better if you populate the dropdown list with a list of select items coming from the server (maybe in the viewbag) only with the options required depending on current state. like this  http://www.compilemode.com/2016/01/bind-dropdownlist-using-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc.html

Comment: Is it possible to use runat="server" on select?

Comment: @newDevGeek I am loading the values ​​directly from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method also.

If you want more validation you can create Custome validation also.

You can get all disable the option in the database then you check if you want to prevent static data compression.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateTicketFromDetails()
{
    var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"];

    var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"];
    var oExcludeItem = new string[] { "ABT", "CDO", "ESU" }; // You can use string array also   
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketStatusInput))
    {
        if (oExcludeItem.Contains(ticketStatusInput))
        {
            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "Please select only enable option";
             });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new TicketResult
        {
            IsValid = false,
            Error = "Please select valid data";
       });
    }
    var lstDisableOption = new List<string>(); // You can also use with List object
    lstDisableOption.Add("ABT");
            lstDisableOption.Add("CDO");
            lstDisableOption.Add("ESU");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketStatusInput))
            {
                if (lstDisableOption.Any(x => x == ticketStatusInput))
                {
                    return Json(new TicketResult
                    {
                        IsValid = false,
                        Error = "Please select only enable option";
                    });
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new TicketResult
                {
                    IsValid = false,
                    Error = "Please select valid data";
                 });
             }
        }

    try
    {
        TicketRegisterResult result;
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // I create a new record variable with all fields
            var record = new TK_DT_RECORDS
            {
                TK_CT_STATUS_ID = ticketStatusInput,
            };
            // We update the ticket data (this will always be done)
            var model = new TicketRegisterModel();
            // We create the new record in the record table and insert it
            result = model.UpdateTicket;

            //If the ticket was not saved, the transaction is finished and we return the error message
            if (!result.Success)
                return Json(new TicketResult
                {
                    IsValid = false,
                    Error = "The changes could not be saved, please try again."
                });
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        //Failed to try to register data in the database
        foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);

        return Json(new TicketResult
        {
            IsValid = false,
            Error = "There was an error creating the ticket, please try again."
        });
    }
    return Json(new TicketResult
    {
        IsValid = true
    });
}
```

Comment: Within this function which would be the options that are enabled and which are not ?

Comment: These two functions work if I did not have to bring a default value but in my case if necessary and that would be the value **FINISHED**

Comment: In the above method, you just need to add disable values in the list or array. now it is dependent on you whether you want to add it from database or from hard-coded. so when user post data from Fron-end you just need to check with that list.

Comment: The value to be loaded in the dropdownlist is the FINISHED one that corresponds to TMN, and arrives from the database, as I do to add that value in the matrix, remember to take into account my business rule, check the question I already added it

Comment: Checking your code, I don't know where you put the value of FINISHED in the dropdownlist, I mean the TMN

Comment: with the first example you use string array

Answer (score 1):

Your question is when you load form with data (finished state), your dropdown should be only available to select assigned or in progress.

Then user sends update request, you should validate, user send values only between in those two, when original data in finished.

This is not the complete code, but the solution.

```
var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"]; 
var idOfOriginalData = Request.Form["id"]; 

//// get the correct or original data. here i uesd get back from database, you can use sessions, viewdata, tempdata 
var originalObj = GetOriginalFromDatabase(idOfOriginalData);

//// then only you can do the validation. 
if ( originalObj.State == "TMN")
{
    var expetedOptions = new string[] { "ASG", "PRC"};

    //// check status that user sent is in expetedOptions
    if ( !expetedOptions.Contains(ticketStatusInput))
    {
        return Json(new TicketResult
        {
            IsValid = false,
            Error = "Please select only enable option";
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do the following but I realized with the debug that the condition is not met, 
check the code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/vlNiTy

Comment: Where are you getting an error or not meeting your condition?

Comment: Do not enter `if (! ExpetedOptions.Contains (ticketStatusInput))`

Comment: Did you check value of ticketStatusInput? Is it a string?

Comment: ticketStatusInput is a string

Comment: Then its not going inside if it is not equal ASG or PRC. Isn't that you expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200926/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-cdev).

Comment: I sent you the business rule that I have to apply to my validation, check the chat

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this might help.
This is just a proof of concept.

Create object model of StatusTypes

```
public class StatusTypes{
public string Key { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Declare variables inside the class

```
public List<StatusTypes> AllowedStatusTypes { get; set; }
public List<StatusTypes> AllStatusTypes { get; set; } = GetAllStatusTypes();
```

Here is the function placeholder for getting all status types

```
public static List<StatusTypes> GetAllStatusTypes()
{
var list = new List<StatusTypes>();
// list = call method/url here to get all types
return list;
}
```

Call this method at the same time you are loading options from database for the "data"

```
public void UpdateAllowedTicketStatusTypes(string statusID)
{
switch(statusID){
    case "TMN":
        AllowedStatusTypes = AllStatusTypes.Where(o => o.Value == "ASG" || o.Value == "PRC").ToList();
        break;
    default:
        AllowedStatusTypes = AllStatusTypes;
        break;
}    
}
```

Then inside your UpdateTicketMethod, you can do this check

```
if(ticketStatusInput == "TMN" && (AllowedStatusTypes.Exists(o => o.Value == "ABT") || AllowedStatusTypes.Exists(o => o.Value == "CDO") || AllowedStatusTypes.Exists(o => o.Value == "ESU"))){
return Json(new TicketResult{
    IsValid = false,
    Error = "Please select valid value."
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be not that optimal solution, but you can make the same request as in your ajax call in your controller via `HttpClient`. Parse the response data and compare with the data that comes from the UI. If selection from the UI doesn't comply to rules - throw error.

Here is a bit of code that can show the idea:

```
// Define InputStatus enum, which represents all available statuses

public async Task<InputStatus> GetValidInputStatus(string url)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(); // or better inject it into controller
    var httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage();

    httpReq.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    httpReq.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpReq);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Parse content string somehow into an InputStatus
    InputStatus validStatus = ParseStatus(content);

    return validStatus;
}

[HttpPost]
public Task<JsonResult> UpdateTicketFromDetails()
{
    var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"]; // Convert it to InputStatus model somehow
    var validStatus = await GetValidInputStatus(url); // Put here the same url as in your ajax call on the UI

    if (validStatus == InputStatus.TMN && 
        (ticketStatusInput == InputStatus.ABT || ticketStatusInput == InputStatus.CDO || ticketStatusInput == InputStatus.ESU))
    // throw, user sent disabled statuses
    else
    // continue
}
```

Comment: Check the latest update I just made, I am presenting a problem with your function

Comment: @SebastianSalazar you should do some coding too :) Define InputStatus enum that represents all your possible statuses, then define function ParseStatus(string content) which will turn content string into enum value, so the result from your url can be parsed. 

I left comments where some changes from your side are required (except httpClient, its optional)

Comment: You can modify the answer you left me by adding the `InputStatus` enum and defining the `ParseStatus` function